# Any way to get OS X-like Open dialog drag-and-drop behaviour on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

In OS X, dragging and dropping a file from the Finder into a system Open File dialog causes the dialog to navigate to the containing folder and select the dragged file.

I would like to have the same behaviour on Windows. Is there any way to achieve this, like an Explorer plugin or something?

Answer (score 0):

[Listary](http://www.listary.com/) provides functionality that is similar (and arguably even more efficient) via their feature called ['Quick Switch'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T9-OtRVeUw)